# Git patch of empty commits

Tags: git

I create an empty commit:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "something important"
```

Sometimes it is useful, e.g. to coordinate 2 (or more) distinct git trees.

However, when I

```
$ git format-patch ...
```

Empty commits are omitted, as they are not associated with any code diff.
Is there a way to include empty commits in a patch ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I made an empty commit, then a non-empty, both on top of an existing repo, then I did `git format-patch @~4..` and it wrote out 4 commits, including the empty one, which is an empty file. Is the problem that the file is empty, and thus won't recreate the empty commit?

Comment: Yeah, this is an issue if you want to recreate the other tree with `git apply-patch`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `--always` to `git format-patch`, but `git am` won't understand how to apply it still.