# git format-patch on empty commit returns unexpected result

Tags: git, patch, git-commit, format-patch

Couldn't find any explanation on git docs on this issue:

If I create a dummy commit, with some dummy diff, I get a normal patch
when I run

`git format-patch -1 -o outgoing/ -p -k`

but if the last commit is an empty commit, generated by

`git commit --allow-empty "Some commit message"`

then the output of the format patch will be an empty patch. If the
first case produces something like this:

```
From 08cfdb2994554d834b89309ca96d9bf513e26a90 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: User <mail@example.com>
Date: Fri, 8 Jan 2016 12:44:57 +0000
Subject: dummy commit


diff --git a/lol.txt b/lol.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f944b38
--- /dev/null
+++ b/lol.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+:)
--
2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
```

then the second case shouldn't generate something like this instead ?

```
From 2d486f25c48780e2e132047e681929fcccb7e60c Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: User <mail@example.com>
Date: Fri Jan 8 12:43:55 2016 +0000
Subject: Some commit message


2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from git mailing list:

Jeff King said:

```
I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.

In the beginning, git's revision-traversal machinery generally does not show 
commits which have no diff. Over the years, commands like "git log"
learned to set the "always_show_header" option to show even empty commits. 
But format-patch never did.
```

And then Junio C Hamano added:

```
The patch based workflow support is geared towards helping the recipient 
of the patches a lot more than the contributors, and to prevent mistakes while 
applying the patches, "am" would stop when it sees such an empty e-mail as you saw 
(in the later part of message I am not quoting). After all, a "format-patch" output 
that does not have any patch would be indistinguishable from discussion e-mail 
messages and the recipient would not want to end up with no-op commits 
that record such messages.

So I think skipping no-op commit from the output was done pretty much deliberately 
and it is definitely not a bug.  I however do not think it is incorrect 
to say that it is a lack of feature that nobody 
so far found necessary or beneficial.

I would not refuse to consider adding a new option to "format-patch" 
to emit such a no-op message, and add a "having no patch is OK, just record a 
no-op commit" option to "am", though.  But I do not see a clear benefit from 
such change--it sounds more like a set of"because we could" not 
"because we need to" changes to me.
```

> thread available at http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-format-patch-on-empty-commit-td7645342.html
>   thanks to @VonC for finding it

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a link?

Comment: @VonC no, it came from the mailing list.. I dont know if they have some kind of public archive..

Comment: This answer came last night, 11h ago, 9 PM  in Lisbon

Comment: OK got it: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-format-patch-on-empty-commit-td7645342.html

Answer (score 3):

Update 2022: With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ead6767ad7f835f4802248371709c4506ad6a4f1/Documentation/git-am.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> learns `--empty=(stop|drop|keep)"` and `--allow-empty` options to tweak what is done to a piece of e-mail without a patch in it.

See "[git-am with mailbox patch fails when it contains a cover letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614598/6309)".

---

2016: original answer:

Note: if the empty commit was not the last, it would work (as mentioned in "[Git patch of empty commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21073488/6309)")

There was a debate about [empty commit patch in this thread back in 2010](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/format-patch-on-permission-change-gives-empty-patch-td5609558.html).

> A half-good news is that [`format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) already takes `--always` command line option to generate a message out of an empty commit, but because it cannot be applied with "`am`", it is rather pointless.

(`--always` is passed [to `git diff-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree))

You need to do some test, but by default, empty commits are indeed not included.

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5c92a451be8050576aa271a82b00727278dc4642/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> learned to write a log-message only output file for empty commits.

See [commit 94c4289](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94c4289435605a9c39951ccebaf82f131e07c255) (03 Mar 2023) by [John Keeping (`johnkeeping`)](https://github.com/johnkeeping).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5c92a45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c92a451be8050576aa271a82b00727278dc4642), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94c4289435605a9c39951ccebaf82f131e07c255): output header for empty commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Keeping</sup>

> When formatting an empty commit, it is surprising that a totally empty file is generated.
> Set the flag to always print the header, matching the behaviour of `git log`.

Comment: Actually `git am` can apply empty patch with correct diff part which changes nothing. As a workaround need to append such diff to `git format-patch --always`  output.

Comment: @IvanRomanov OK. Maybe this has changed since I wrote the answer in early 2016)