# git-am with mailbox patch fails when it contains a cover letter

Tags: git, mutt, mailing-list, mbox, git-am

When running git-am to apply a patch series I had saved into an mbox file from a mailing list, if the mbox also contains the cover letter (otherwise known as PATCH [0/N]), it complains as follows:

```
128 git … am --3way ~/patches/sample.mbox
Patch is empty.
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

It is true the cover letter is an empty patch as there isn't a patch delimiter contained within, but I would've thought `git am` would be smart enough to notice it and skip it altogether. This is not a major nuisance as I can skip adding this patch into the mbox from mutt without trouble, but sometimes a patch series arrives to the mailing list somewhat scrambled, and I can't just copy the entire thread into the same mbox.
Alternatively I can manually skip the patch and it will apply smoothly.

Is there any way I can instruct git am to skip patch number 0 when it is indeed a cover letter?

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ead6767ad7f835f4802248371709c4506ad6a4f1/Documentation/git-am.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> learns `--empty=(stop|drop|keep)"` and `--allow-empty` options to tweak what is done to a piece of e-mail without a patch in it.

So try again (Git 2.35+) with:

```
git … am --empty=keep --allow-empty --3way ~/patches/sample.mbox
```

See [commit 9e7e41b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e7e41bf19ed10469f9adb60669b1699c81b8ea6), [commit 7c096b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c096b8d61e1276acb6f84bf446cfe74578382a0), [commit 552038e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/552038e26cfa2a1b5a7843567ca7ab39a573951f) (09 Dec 2021) by [徐沛文 (Aleen) (`aleen42`)](https://github.com/aleen42).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ead6767](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ead6767ad7f835f4802248371709c4506ad6a4f1), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`am`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c096b8d61e1276acb6f84bf446cfe74578382a0): support `--empty=<option>` to handle empty patches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: 徐沛文 (Aleen)</sup>

> Since that the command '`git-format-patch`' can include patches of commits that emit no changes, the '`git-am`' command should also support an option, named as '`--empty`', to specify how to handle those empty patches.
>
> In this commit, we have implemented three valid options ('`stop`', '`drop`' and '`keep`').

`git am` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7c096b8d61e1276acb6f84bf446cfe74578382a0/Documentation/git-am.txt#L67-L74):

> ### `--empty=(stop|drop|keep)`
>
> By default, or when the option is set to '`stop`', the command
> errors out on an input e-mail message lacking a patch
> and stops into the middle of the current am session.
>
> When this option is set to '`drop`', skip such an e-mail message instead.
>
> When this option is set to '`keep`', create an empty commit,
> recording the contents of the e-mail message as its log.